# How to repeat the alarm ON every monday or every tuesday

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, alarm

The following is the code to set the alarm once,

```
-(IBAction) alaramSetButton:(id)sender{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    NSString *dateTimeSetting=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTimePicker.date];

    //Date format mm/dd/yy
    NSLog(@"dateTimeSetting %@",dateTimeSetting);

    [self scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate: [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTimeSetting]];
    [self alarmMessage:@"Alarm setted"];
    [dateFormatter release];
}
```

Its working properly,but i am trying to set the alarm or repeat the alarm on every monday or every tuesday, For this i am not getting how to start or what functionality to add. Any suggestions will be very helpfull. Thanks in Advance.